# Output "System.out.println" into Emacs Cider's REPL (or other buffer)

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

I am using a `Java` library in `Clojure`. It does output many things directly to the console using `System.out.println`.

I am using the latest Cider with Emacs. I am starting Cider with `cider-jack-in`. However, I can see these outputs. I thought they would be copied to the *nrepl-server* buffer, but it is not.

I also tried to run `(alter-var-root #'*out* (constantly *out*))` in the REPL, but no success.

What am I missing in how this should be done, if it can be done at all.

Comment: Take a look in the *messages* buffer, I think they go there

Comment: The messages buffer simply logs the communication between CIDER and the nREPL server.

Comment: The output should appear in the REPL buffer normally. If it doesn't - file a ticket on github and we'll look into the problem.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov ok, will retry and test and report if there is an issue, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace the `java.io.PrintStream` assigned to `System.out` with one that will forward everything to `clojure.core/*out*` (which is an instance of `java.io.PrintWriter`). To do that you have to create an adapter from `PrintStream` to `PrintWriter`. I haven't found an existing one in the Java SDK API but there is one in [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/output/WriterOutputStream.html) (or you can implement it by yourself):

```clj
(import (java.io PrintStream)
        (org.apache.commons.io.output WriterOutputStream))

(-> *out*
    (WriterOutputStream.)
    (PrintStream.)
    (System/setOut))
```

From now on when you call `System.out.println` anywhere in your JVM the output will be passed to `clojure.core/*out*`.