# start boot task after cider-jack-in

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider, boot-clj

After starting a boot project via cider-jack-in, how can I start a specific boot task?

In the repl `(dir boot.user)` reveals the tasks defined in `build.boot`. However, invoking one by e.g. `(dev)` has no effect, at least the ring server defined in that task can not be connected to. when using `boot dev` from the commandline, it works. The reason why I need to switch to cider-jack-in, is that it looks in the shell/cider-connect approach there is no way to print/log to an emacs buffer instead of to the default shell (which is mixed with all the compilation messages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute

```
(boot (dev))
```

Calling `(dev)` will produce your task function which you need to pass to `boot` function for execution.

Comment: nice, this works. Unfortunately the printing goes nowhere at the moment... Would you know how to handle this?

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37421972/597473. If not I can check later.

Comment: You can also check messages buffer in emacs for your output.

Comment: Yes, it works now. I guess it was another boot process in the background disturbing it. thanks a lot!